Questions on derivative of absolutely continuous function
Let us consider an absolutely continuous function $f:[0,h] \to \mathbb{R}$.
Then, it is well-known that $f'(t)$ exists almost everywhere for $t \in [0,h]$.
What I wonder to check if it is true is the fact:
If there's some $t_{0} \in [0,h]$ such that $\exists f'(t_{0})$, then there exists a sequence $\{t_{n}\} \subseteq [0,h]$ such that $t_{n}$ converges to $t_{0}$ and $f'(t_{n})$ converges to $f'(t_{0})$.
I obviously know that such a choice of $t_n$ cannot be arbitrary because $f'$ is not continuous in general. The point is that there "exists" such a sequence ensuring the convergences.
Thank you for considering this.

I would like to find a countable union $U$ of real intervals with the property that $f(x)=\int_0^x1_U(x)dx$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with derivative different from $0$ or $1.$

I believe that the statement is false in general. Let me try to construct a counterexample where for every $x$ the derivative is either nonexistent (necessarily a null set), zero, one, or at exactly one $x$: one half. The one half then cannot be approximated by the derivatives at other values of the argument $x.$
For each positive integer $n$ divide the interval $[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)$ into $2^n$ intervals $I_{n,k}$ of equal length
$$\lambda(I_{n,k})=2^{-n}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right).$$
Let $U$ be the union of all $I_{n,k}$ where $k$ is even:
$$U=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{l=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}I_{n,2l}.$$
For any $x\in I_{N,K}$ we have
$$\begin{align}
f(x)=\int_{t=0}^x1_U(t)dt&=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\lambda(I_{n,2l})+\sum_{l=0}^{\lfloor{K/2}\rfloor}\lambda(I_{N,2l})+R(x) \\
&=\frac1{2(N+1)}+\frac{K}{2^{N+1}}\left(\frac1N-\frac1{N+1}\right)+R(x)
\end{align}$$
where $R(x)=0$ if $K$ is odd and $R(x)=\left(x-\frac1{N+1}\right)\mod 2^{-N}\left(\frac1N-\frac1{N+1}\right)$ if $K$ is even.
As $x\to0$ the first term is asymptotically $x/2$ while the second and third terms are lower order. This means that $f$ is differentiable from the right at $x=0$ with derivative $1/2.$
Extending U by its mirror image on the real line leads to an absolutely continuous function $f$ that is differentiable at $x=0$ and at every other real argument except for a countable number of points, and whose derivative is $0$ or $1$ at each of those arguments except at $x=0$ where it is $1/2.$
